# How Import (merge) a reg file using delphi?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

I have several .reg (Windows registry) files (generated by an external application) that need to merge into the windows registry. Now i'm using the `ShellExecuteEx` function to call the `regedit.exe` application, passing the filename  as parameter (And works fine), but I'm wondering if exist any WinAPi function or another way to merge that file without call to the `regedit.exe` application.

Comment: Does `RegLoadKey` or one of its friends do the job?

Comment: `RegLoadKey()` loads binary hive files that were created with `RegSaveKey()`.  It does not load .reg files, which are text files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect that the answer is no. Via the winapi, you'd read the file as a .ini file, and make the appropriate registry modifications accordingly.  I would be surprised if regedit.exe does something different than that.

Comment: There's indeed no api to import a regfile. You can add `/s` as a parameter to suppress the confirmation dialog if you like.